# Exporting Hive table with Sqoop, some rows are not delimited

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, sqoop

I have a table generated with Hive (on an Amazon Elastic MapReduce JobFlow). I can see that the data is located at `hdfs:///mnt/hive_081/warehouse/[table name]`.

I have wrapped Sqoop in a jar (without changing anything), and uploaded it to the master node for testing.

I run my sqoop jar as such:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -cp /home/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar:/home/hadoop:/home/hadoop/hadoop-tools-1.0.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-tools.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar:/home/hadoop/lib/*:/home/hadoop/lib/jetty-ext/* -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/6 -Dhadoop.log.file=syslog -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/6/tmp -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/native/Linux-i386-32 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /home/hadoop/fsa/anet-dw-sqoop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $ARGS
```

where $ARGS is (the sensitive mysql flags are omitted):

```
--export-dir hdfs:///mnt/hive_081/warehouse/[table name] --input-null-non-string '\\\N' --direct --input-null-string '\\\N' --username root --input-fields-terminated-by '\0x009' --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --table [table name]
```

I am testing this on ten rows of data that I mocked up. No null values. Each row is unique in repeating the same number in all columns. When I execute the command, I get many

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "231 231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231     231      231     231     231     231     231     -25     231     -25     -25     231     231     -25"
```

I consistently get this message for the same FOUR (of 10) rows, every time (ignore the negative values, those are columns of TINYINT that couldn't fit the number).

You can see that there is much less space between the first two values in the row. Is this my problem? What would cause this? FYI, if I copy the data file from the HDFS to the local FS, and point to it, I do not get this message - but also the data didn't get to its destination :/. Anyway, I'm trying to automate a multi-step process so I would like to be able to operate directly on the HDFS data without copying anything over.

Any advice much appreciated!

**UPDATE**: This also happens when I use commas as delimiters. It is observed for the same four rows. When I restrict the Hive table to only ONE row (and NOT one of the erroneous rows from previous tests), the same error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In the arguments to sqoop-export, --input-fields-terminated-by value must be WITHOUT quotes. This worked:

--input-fields-terminated-by \t